# way for persisting data throughout android application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

can any one help me in finding way for persisting data throughout application(For ex: session detail) ?

Comment: Use SettingPreffrences.Its the best way

Comment: See this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared preferences in android

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Also you can store data in sqlite database and there is great library you can use for it. 
http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml